# JAX-RS cant get XML response type from GET method

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, jax-rs

i am building a basic Webservices with JAX-RS

here are the GET methods:

```
    /**
 * Returns all songs
 * @return all songs
 */
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Collection<Song> getAllSongs() {
    return SongsRXStore.getInstance().getAllSongs();
}

/**
 * Returns song with id: "id"
 * @param id the "id"
 * @return song with id: "id"
 */
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response getSong(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    Song song = SongsRXStore.getInstance().getSongById(id);
    if (song != null)
        return Response.ok(song).build();
    else
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND + ": No Song found with id " + id).build();
}
```

It seems just fine as it is but I cannot get XML type back.

here is requesting all songs(first method above) as json and xml. As you can see only the json is correctly returned but not the xml.
[image]

same with requesting just one specific song(second method form above):
[image]

How can I make it work please?

EDIT: @XmlRootElemnt tag is of course allready added to my POJO_Bean Song.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "song")
public class Song {
```

Comment: Please include code as text and **not as** image. Thx.

Comment: ok done, do you have any solution to my problem though?

Answer (score 1):

More than one media type may be declared in the same `@Produces` declaration.

The following code example shows how this is done:

```
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public String doGetAsXmlOrJson() {
    ...
}
```

The `doGetAsXmlOrJson` method will get invoked if either of the media types `application/xml` and `application/json` is acceptable. If both are equally acceptable, the former will be chosen because it occurs first.

See [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipxf/index.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your answer. unfortunately this is what I am allready doing and it does not work...both get emthods are producing xml and json allready. BUT it only makes json response while XML responses are empty childs(see screenshots of console ouput)

Comment: try to add `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your Song class.

Comment: allready done sorry for not including into question.I am going to add it now

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I got the answer, but it somehow started to give out the ids instead of empty xml children. I have set the getId method to public from private prior jsut for seeing if it does soemthing and it did(!!!!)

So I set all get and set emthods in my Song-class to public and it works now.

Does it make any sense? If yes pls elaborate as I am confused now why it works now...